# java bean copy limited field for faster transport

Tags: java, spring

I want get a smaller order from big order which hold fields only needed, eg: orderId, province, productName. in this way i can saving a lot bandwidth and serialize time.

Now i need your help because i can not get all productName by spring BeanWrapper.

```
    // i want get all names, not only index 1, how to do ?
    keepFields.add("productInfos[1].name");
```

reference resources:https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.18.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beans (3.3)

my test code:

```java
package com.hisen.copy.smaller.utils;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean.Address;
import com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean.Order;
import com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean.ProductInfo;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessorFactory;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * copy a smaller bean
 *
 * @author hisenyuan
 * @date 2020-09-26 14:49
 */
public class CopySmallerUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order = getOrder();
        Order smallerOrder = new Order();
        List<String> keepFields = Lists.newArrayList();
        keepFields.add("orderId");
        keepFields.add("address.province");
        // i want get all names, not only index 1, how to do ?
        keepFields.add("productInfos[1].name");
        copyProperties(order, smallerOrder, keepFields);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println("src:" + gson.toJson(order));
        System.out.println("dst:" + gson.toJson(smallerOrder));
//        src:{"address":{"province":"B","city":"A","county":"C"},"productInfos":[{"productId":0,"name":"name0","price":1,"num":0,"imgUrl":"url1"},{"productId":0,"name":"name1","price":2,"num":0,"imgUrl":"url1"},{"productId":0,"name":"name2","price":3,"num":0,"imgUrl":"url1"}]}
//        dst:{"address":{"province":"B"},"productInfos":[{"productId":0,"num":0},{"productId":0,"name":"name1","num":0}]}
    }


    /**
     * only copy fields you want
     * @param src
     * @param dst
     * @param fields
     */
    private static void copyProperties(Order src, Order dst, List<String> fields) {
        BeanWrapper srcWarp = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(src);
        BeanWrapper dstWarp = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(dst);
        dstWarp.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(10);
        dstWarp.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);
        fields.forEach(f -> dstWarp.setPropertyValue(f, srcWarp.getPropertyValue(f)));
    }

    /**
     * getOrder
     * @return
     */
    private static Order getOrder() {
        Order order = new Order();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCity("A");
        address.setProvince("B");
        address.setCounty("C");
        order.setAddress(address);
        List<ProductInfo> productInfos = Lists.newArrayList();
        int times = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            ProductInfo productInfo = new ProductInfo();
            productInfo.setName("name" + i);
            productInfo.setImgUrl("url" + 1);
            productInfo.setPrice(new BigDecimal(i + 1));
            productInfos.add(productInfo);
        }
        order.setProductInfos(productInfos);
        return order;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author hisenyuan
 * @date 2020-09-26 14:44
 */
public class Order {
    private String orderId;
    private Address address;
    private List<ProductInfo> productInfos;

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<ProductInfo> getProductInfos() {
        return productInfos;
    }

    public void setProductInfos(List<ProductInfo> productInfos) {
        this.productInfos = productInfos;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean;

/**
 * @author hisenyuan
 * @date 2020-09-26 14:42
 */
public class Address {
    private String province;
    private String city;
    private String county;

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return county;
    }

    public void setCounty(String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }
}
```

```
package com.hisen.copy.smaller.bean;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * @author hisenyuan
 * @date 2020-09-26 14:45
 */
public class ProductInfo {
    private long productId;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal discount;
    private int num;
    private String imgUrl;

    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(BigDecimal discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Introduce DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Data Transfer Object (DTO)**. DTOs are assentially like a Java Class, but it doesn't contain any business logic. Think about that like a way to reduce a number of remote calls by using a simplified object instead of your original entity class.

For performing a entity-DTO conversion where the data in two models may be similar you can use a library like *ModelMapper*: http://modelmapper.org/

You can check this tutorial as well: https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: thank you for your answer. as a provider, consumer tell what they needed then rentrun, It's a variable process, not a fixed. ModelMapper it simply to format field look like PropertyEditor.